# Custom caching of xml and properties file in java?

Tags: java, xml, caching, properties

I want write a class which is use to cache xml and properties file for certain interval and cache should be updated in next same request if there ll be any change in source.

so can any one tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Create class that parses data and exposes interface to get the data. 
Let's call the method `getProperty()`. You can create member variable `Date lastUpdated`. Every time you call `getProperty()` you check whether the timeout is already expired. If it is you read data from file. Otherwise you just return the data.